# PHP form submit not reloading full page, must submit twice

Tags: php, forms

I'm having some trouble with a form I created seemingly not reloading the entire page, but just the portion with the form. I'm using a MVC method which uses a switch statement to load different tabbed selections.

The relevant bits are here:

First we check a user state variable, along with checking if their role is set. This all seems to work fine with the if selection. After submitting, the proper included page loads.

```
if ($user_state == "6" && empty($user_role))
            {
            $role_or_overview = 'Select Role';
            $role_or_overview_page = './php/select_role.php';
            }
            else
            {
            $role_or_overview = 'Overview';
            $role_or_overview_page = './php/overview.php';
            }
```

Which leads into a a switch statement which selects which php script to load into the tab...

```
switch($user_menu) {
            default:

            case($role_or_overview):
            include($role_or_overview_page);
            break;

            case('User Submit'):
            include('./php/user_entry.php');
            break;
                   }
```

That switch statement is tied into another, which determines what tabs to display. These both occur near the beginning of the entire page code as includes, before the form.

```
switch($user_state)
{
 default:

echo '<div class="nav">'; // start div nav
div_button('', 'Overview', $user_menu);
echo '</div>'; // end div nav

echo '<div class="clear-both">';
echo '</div>';
 break;

case '0':
// Regular User Menu

echo '<div class="nav">'; // start div nav
div_button('', 'Overview', $user_menu);
echo '</div>'; // end div nav

echo '<div class="nav">'; // start div nav
div_button('menu', 'User Submit', $user_menu);
echo '</div>'; // end div nav

echo '<div class="clear-both">';
echo '</div>'

}
```

A simple form allows the user to select the role and self posts...

```
echo '<form action = "./" method = "post" name="role_select">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="post_role" value="ROLE1">';
echo '<input type="submit" name="DEPT" value="ROLE1">';
echo '</form>';
echo '<form action = "./" method = "post" name="role_select">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="post_role" value="ROLE2">';
echo '<input type="submit" name="DEPT" value="ROLE2">';
echo '</form>';
```

At the top of my index I check for the posted value and set the user state so that the tabs I want to appear, appear

```
if ($_POST['post_role'])
{
$user_role = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post_role']);
$user_state=0;
}
```

The problem I'm running into is after submitting the form, it seems localized. I setup some test echoes, and while the values reach the included form page, they do not reach the entire page until a tab is clicked (or a form is clicked a second time when I have the php script not change for debugging).

There is a lot of code I've intentionally left out, but it all works. The $user_menu is just an easy way to pass the tab names/values so they can be selected and loaded in the same page. I just can't get this role to post properly and choose a new switch case.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: this is in no way related to MVC design pattern, and there is no such thing as "mvc method" .. i am removing the tag

Comment: How are you setting `$user_state`, `$user_role` and `$user_menu`?

Comment: Also ... [**please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: $user_state is set by some if statements, the "normal" user I'm going for does not exist in any database, all the other users do. This view is just for them. $user_role is set by the form inputs I posted. $user_menu is inconsequential, really, and just passes something like "User Select" which tells the app overall what page to include.